# Modify Java objects based on script

Tags: java, string, interpreter

I have a table of information (.csv-file) that I take each row of and convert into instances of a Java class. One of the columns in the table (currently not filled in) should contain scripts of some kind to modify another type of object.

I need the script to be able to call a selection of methods with parameters (some have return types), optionally only if a condition is true. Calling a method several times with different receivers is also essential (like with a for-loop). The more I think about it, the more it looks like a separate programming language.

At first I was going to create a simple interpreter, but then I thought of more and more features that I would need and it quickly became a too large project for me. I hope I explained my problem well enough. Can anyone point me in the direction of something that I can use to accomplish my goal? The only thing I can think of would be a library of some kind, but other solutions are more than welcome.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understood it. so you have a set of object that need to do something depends on what the parameter is. can't you just use a switch statement? beside most of the time you program is bigger than you expect it to be. so grow up and deal with it :P

Comment: I need to be able to use expressions and other features which are already present in a lot of languages, so I would rather use something that already exists than spend time on creating something new.